# Setting a limit on the number of times a note is created

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I am currently working on a postIt for my website where pressing the plus button would create an editable post it/sticky notes. I am done with that part now but I am struggling with the next part which is limiting the number of sticky notes to just 4. I tried having a global variable that would serve as a counter so when the counter is 3, it should stop creating more sticky notes but unfortunately, it is not working.

Here is the link to my workable code:
[Sticky note](https://codepen.io/mooeSaad/pen/OOZOGe)

And this is my futile attempt at limiting the number of sticky notes to 4.

```
$("#create").click(function(){
var count = 0;
if( count < 4){
    $("#create").click(function() {
    $(this).before("<textarea></textarea>");
    }); 
    count++;
          }
}
```

Can anyone please give me pointers as to how to limit the notes to 4? I have been working on this forever now.

Comment: It's not working because that's not a global variable. Everytime `$("#create").click()` fires, the `count` variable is reset to 0. Taking a closer look, you've actually created that event listener twice..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just move `var count = 0;` outside the event listener and remove the inner event listener:

```
var count = 0;                                       // outside the scope of the event listener function bellow so it won't get destroyed/recreated each time the function get called (ie when a clicks happen)
$("#create").click(function() {
    if(count < 4) {                                  // we haven't yet exceeded the limits
        $(this).before("<textarea></textarea>");     // don't attach another click event listener on #create (we are already in one) so just create the note.
        count++;
    }
});
```

Comment: And if I wanted to make the plus disappear, then in that case is there any js function to do that?

Comment: There is jQuery's `hide` or `remove`.

Comment: Inside `if` statement add another one after `count++` to check if `count === 4`, if so then call `$(this).remove();` (to remove the button permanently) or `$(this).hide();` (to hide it for later use).

Answer (score 2):

Everytime you click create, count the number of `textarea` elements then determine if you should create a new one:

```
$("#create").click(function() {
    var count = $("textarea");
    if (count.length < 4) {
        $(this).before("<textarea></textarea>");
    }
});
```

You can even add a `class` in the newly created `textarea` to ensure that you only count the ones created by this function.

HTML:

```
<textarea>This is not part of the group.</textarea>

<textarea class="sticky">This is a sticky note you can type and edit.</textarea>

<div id="create">+</div>
```

JS:

```
$("#create").click(function() {
  var count = $("textarea.sticky");
  if (count.length < 4) {
      $(this).before("<textarea class='sticky'></textarea>");
  }
});
```

Comment: What if he has other textareas somewhere on the page? This is just not the solution to go for..

Comment: As mentioned, a class can be added and use that in the selector to ensure that only the `textarea` created by the function will be counted.

Comment: Yes, but your answer doesn't reflect that. Your _answer_ is to just count all textareas. You're giving advise on how to improve the code afterwards. It would be better to show an example of how to change the textareas with a class and use that with your js code. Because then it's actually an answer.

Comment: Much better. +1 from me :)

Comment: This is why I love it here! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are defining your `count` variable inside of your `click` event handler. As such, every time you click the element, the counter gets reset. You also shouldn't make use of a secondary click handler inside the main one.

To resolve this, bring the `count` variable outside of the click handler:

```
var count = 0;
$("#create").click(function() {
    if (count < 3) {
        $(this).before("<textarea></textarea>");
        count++;
    }
});
```

Note that the conditional should check that the `count` is less than **3**, because it increases the count after creation. If it is set to check if the count is less than 4, **five** notes would be created.

In order to also hide the `+` after creating the fourth element, you would use:

```
if (count == 3) {
  $(this).hide();
}
```

After increasing the count.

This can be seen working [**here**](https://codepen.io/Obsidian-Age/pen/pdVpzE).

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: And if I wanted to disappear the plus button after the fourth note is created then how would I go about doing that?

Comment: You would use `if (count == 3) { $(this).hide(); }`. I've updated the example to showcase that :)